Examples of graded subrings of $\mathbb Q(T)$
The following question came up in some discussion on some very unrelated matters.
A graded algebra $A$ is an algebra $A$ with a decomposition $A = \oplus_{i \in \mathbb Z} A_i$ such that $A_i A_j \subset A_{i+j}$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb Z$.
A prototypical (non-trivial) example is of course the ring of Laurent polynomials $\mathbb Z[T^{\pm 1}]$.
What are other non-trivial examples of graded algebras $A \subset \mathbb Q(T)$ inside the ring of rational functions over $\mathbb Q$? Is it possible to understand all (non-trivial) "gradable" subrings of $\mathbb Q (T)$? (By non-trivial I mean that $A \neq A_0$).
It is not clear if this question is trivial or interesting. In any case I was unable to locate relevant literature. I'd be delighted if there's an expert who could say something about this question.
Thank you very much in advance!

Of course, given one example of a graded algebra $A$, one also has all of its Veronese subrings $A^{(d)}$, whose $k$th graded piece is $[A]_{kd}$, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}[T]^{(4)} = \mathbb{Z}[T^4]$. This example is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[T]$, but in general Veronese subrings are not isomorphic to their base ring.

The word "gradable" is indeed useful and maybe it's better to use it when the grading is not fixed (especially when dealing with subalgebras of a given algebra).
